# WiX unresolved reference to symbol media 1 in section fragment

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I am trying to build my WiX Project in Visual Studio 2010, but everytime I build, I receive the following error messages:

> Unresolved reference to symbol 'Media1' in section 'Fragment:'
>
> Unresolved reference to symbol 'Media1' in section 'Product{67DC7AE3-030F-4A24-AC3F-7AE7D0C32D07}'

The project includes one Product.wxs file and one heat-generated wxs someComponents.wxs (my fragment) file. I am referencing components in the heat-generated wxs file in Product.wxs. The sections where I am getting the errors are as follows:

**Product.wxs file**

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop"/>        
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="Aspex" Name="Company">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="My App" >
          <Component Id="appFromSomeComponent">
            <File Id="AppFromSomeComponentexe" 
                  Name="AppFromSomeComponent.exe"
                  Source="$(var.AppFromSomeComponentBin)\AppFromSomeComponent.exe" />
            <RemoveFile Id="PurgeAppFolder" Name="*.*" On="uninstall" />
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>

<!-- Shortcuts in the start menu-->
<DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder2">
  <Component Id="StartMenuMyApp">
    <Shortcut Id="MyAPP" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder2"
              Name="My App" 
              WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" 
              Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]appFromSomeComponent.exe"/>
    <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder2" On="uninstall"/>
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" 
                   Key="Software\Microsoft\appFromSomeComponent" 
                   Name="installed" 
                   Type="integer" 
                   Value="1" 
                   KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>

  <Component Id="UninstallStartMenuShortcut">
    <Shortcut Id="UninstallProduct"
      Name="Uninstall My App"
      Target="[SystemFolder]msiexec.exe"
      Arguments="/x [ProductCode]"
      Description="Uninstall My App" />
    <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder4" On="uninstall"/>
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" 
                   Key="Software\Microsoft\MyAppUninstall"
                   Name="installed"
                   Type="integer"
                   Value="1"
                   KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

**someComponents.wxs**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Component Id="cmpEFCBE60AE731F2F72E1E191A31A5C932" 
                   Guid="{41805DA3-9F2A-45D3-82F7-46357FDA91F1}">
            <File Id="filE84D9AAD661C2BCD945C740C9DF8F5EE" 
                  KeyPath="yes"
                  Source="$(var.AppFromSomeComponentBin)\AppFromSomeComponent.exe" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="cmpA7CD6B191FCDC253D5418CC203735124"
                   Guid="{1B1B6D45-B2A3-4D1B-AD1C-645D9D8AEE6E}">
             <File Id="fil042C8008BCA6DCC4254D61C306D2DA18"
                   KeyPath="yes"
                   Source="$(var.AppFromSomeComponentBin)\AppFromSomeComponent.exe.config" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="cmp6A4D0A31B68BE7D2215111EE5B24D78A"
                   Guid="{BE1094E1-2658-4FB7-B3BE-172C7D90D2C5}">
            <File Id="fil5038053B907D45250FC4F7FB1AE3E3C0"
                  KeyPath="yes" 
                  Source="$(var.AppFromSomeComponentBin)\SomeDll.dll" />
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="AppFromSomeComponentBin">
        <ComponentRef Id="cmpEFCBE60AE731F2F72E1E191A31A5C932" />
        <ComponentRef Id="cmpA7CD6B191FCDC253D5418CC203735124" />
        <ComponentRef Id="cmp6A4D0A31B68BE7D2215111EE5B24D78A" />
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

If someone could point me in the right direction to resolve this issue--or maybe point out something I am missing--that would be greatly appreciated! Also please let me know if any additional information is needed to help answer this question, I try and provide as much information as possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error message is trying say that you are missing a `Media` element with `Id='1'`. Usually, you'll find the `Media` element under the `Product` element. You just need to add something like:

```
<Media Id='1' />
```

You can then add other attributes to the `Media` element to compress your files into a cabinet. With later versions of the WiX toolset you can use the `MediaTemplate` element instead of the `Media` element to create multiple cabinets that do not exceed a certain size. That's great if you end up with lots of files.