# Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixComponentGroup:Product.Generated' in section 'Product:{3544FDE1-36BF-49CC-A05F-4FE4AA685F00}'

Tags: asp.net, wix

I have project in ASP.NET 3.5 framework in VS2008 and trying to migrate to 4.5.1 framework in VS2013. While compiling I am getting error as:

```
 "Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixComponentGroup:Product.Generated' in section 'Product:{3544FDE1-36BF-49CC-A05F-4FE4AA685F00}' ".
```

I have tried below links having solutions but still unable to resolve the issue.

1. [LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixComponentGroup:Product.Generated' in section 'Product:*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386211/lght0094-unresolved-reference-to-symbol-wixcomponentgroupproduct-generated-i)
2. [WiX unresolved reference to symbol media 1 in section fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400208/wix-unresolved-reference-to-symbol-media-1-in-section-fragment)

I have a setup file which contains products.wxs file along with references and include files.

Code:
product.wxs

```
  <Feature Id="ProductFeature">
   <ComponentGroupRef Id="Product.Generated"  />
</Feature>
```

Your help will be most appreciated.Please let me know as soon as possible.

Comment: Simply delete the reference.

Comment: @Amruta Udgiri : Got solution for this../]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the thing was I was using -cg Flaskr
but in my .wxs I had

```
 ComponentGroupRef Id="FLASKR"
```

I hope this will help!